# Deactivate profile in NetBeans' Maven custom goal definitions

Tags: maven, netbeans, maven-profiles

I have a POM with two profiles. The first profile should be active by default. Further I want to create a Maven custom Goal in NetBeans. For this goal the default profile shall be deactivated and the other profile shall be activated.

**Profile activation conditions:**

```
<profile>
        <id>profile-1</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!activate2</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
</profile>

<profile>
        <id>profile-2</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>activate2</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
</profile>
```

**Maven Goal deifinitions:**

[image: Maven Goal definitions]

The problem is that the property set in this window does not affect the activation of my profiles.

I also tried to activate `profile-2` and deactivate `profile-1` (when it was set to `activateByDefault`) in the field 'Activate Profiles' but the deactivation with `!profile-1` doesn't seem to work here.

Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: What is the version of maven and jdk? With maven 3.3.9 and java 1.8.0_231 it works fine. And deactivation with !profile-1 in Active profiles field also works.